# Python OOP issue: How a function in a class is getting input value, when it is not mentioned in __init__() function as a parameter?

Tags: python, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I am relatively new to object oriented programming and I am currently working on Generative Adversarial Networks project. I came across maxout activation function. The function is defined through maxout class. See the code below:

```
class maxout(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_pieces):
        
        super(maxout, self).__init__()
        
        self.num_pieces = num_pieces
        
    def forward(self, x):
        
        assert x.shape[1] % self.num_pieces == 0  # 625 % 5 = 0
        
        ret = x.view(*x.shape[:1], # batch_size
                      x.shape[1] // self.num_pieces, 
                      self.num_pieces, # num_pieces
                      *x.shape[2:]    )
                     
        ret, _ = ret.max(dim=2)
        
        return ret
```

This maxout function was later on used in a discriminator class. Following is the code for discriminator class.

```
class discriminator(torch.nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        super(discriminator, self).__init__()
        
        self.fcn = torch.nn.Sequential(
            # Fully connected layer 1
            torch.nn.Linear(
                in_features = 784,
                out_features=240,
                bias = True
            ),
            maxout(5),
            
            # Fully connected layer 2
            torch.nn.Linear(
                in_features = 48,
                out_features=1,
                bias = True
            )  )
        
    def forward(self, batch):
        inputs = batch.view(batch.size(0), -1)
        outputs = self.fcn(inputs)
        outputs = outputs.mean(0)
        return outputs.view(1)  # it will return a single value
```

The code is working fine but as per my naive understanding of Object oriented programming, the value of 'x' in forward() function in maxout class should be provided through **init**() function.

My question is: How input 'x' is being received by forward() function of maxout class,with out getting input through **init**() function.

Another way to put this question is: How output of Linear layer in discriminator class is passed to maxout function as 'x'?

Comment: "The code is working fine but as per my naive understanding of Object oriented programming, the value of 'x' in forward() function in maxout class should be provided through init() function." No, it is a *parameter* to the `forward` method.

Comment: `discriminator.forward` has the same parameter; it's named `batch` instead of `x`, but it is used in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing layers to the constructior of the `Sequential` model, which is assigned to `self.fcn`, than you in `discriminator.forward` are calling this moddel. It's `__call__` method than calls all the forward functions of the layers it contains.

You can imagine something like this is going on

```py
...
def forward(self, batch):
   return torch.nn.Linear(
       in_features = 48,
       out_features=1,
       bias = True
   ).forward(
       maxout(5).forward(
           torch.nn.Linear(
                in_features = 784,
                out_features=240,
                bias = True
           ).forward(batch.view(batch.size(0), -1)
       )
    ).mean(0).view(1)
```

Comment: Hi, i got much clarity.

Comment: A bit confusion is regarding discriminator.forward. Does __call__ method automatically get invoked when discriminator.forward is called (as i didn't explicitly mention __call__ method). 

if yes, then what's the theory/procedure behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Methods differ from regular functions only by the fact that their first argument is the object of the class in which method is defined, and this first argument can be supplied with the dot operator.
Only the programmer decides which values to pass through `__init__` to assign them to object attributes, and which to pass as parameteres following the first, `self`, argument. There is no requirment to pass all values that we are giving to other methods through the `__init__` method first.

To answer your question:
`torch.nn.Sequential` saves the list of functions you pass, in this example it is of length 3, and outputs some callable object (an object that can behave like a function). You save it to `self.fcn`. Then, when you call `self.fcn`, it calls the `forward` method of the first `torch.nn.Linear`, then passes it's return value to the `forward` method of the `maxout(5)` object - that's where the `x` is given! - and then passes the output of the `maxout(5)` object to the `forward` method of the second `torch.nn.Linear` and returns the result.

Comment: Hi, I am much clear about the process. It will be great if answer the following confusion in my mind. 


A bit confusion is regarding discriminator.forward. Does call method automatically get invoked when discriminator.forward is called (as i didn't explicitly mention call method). if yes, then what's the theory/procedure behind it.